# How to know if app has Visible Windows in Cocoa swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

There is method in AppDelegate like this:

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

with using this function and inside this function we can get true or false for `hasVisibleWindows`, my question is here that I want access the value of hasVisibleWindows outside of function, also the way that function work is that we should click on the icon to make function work, in my question I want get the value of hasVisibleWindows without clicking on icon, is there another way to know if the app `NSApplication.shared` has visible windows?

update:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window1: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    private lazy var window2: NSWindow = NSWindow()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        buildWindow()
    }
    
    private func buildWindow() {

        window1 = makeWindow(title: "Window 1", isReleasedWhenClosed: false)
        window2 = makeWindow(title: "Window 2", isReleasedWhenClosed: false)

        // You can close the windows or minimize them and it will return false, if you let just 1 window open it will return true.
        // You can try all posibale things in 5 sec, close both windows or minimize both or what you like.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(5)) {
            print(nsApplication.hasVisibleWindows)
        }
        
    }
    
}

@discardableResult
func makeWindow(title: String, isReleasedWhenClosed: Bool) -> NSWindow {
    
    let window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable]
    window.backingType = .buffered
    window.isReleasedWhenClosed = isReleasedWhenClosed
    
    window.setFrame(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 200.0)), display: true)
    window.title = title
    window.center()
    window.setFrameAutosaveName(window.title)
    window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
    return window
    
}

extension NSApplication {
    
    var hasVisibleWindows: Bool {

        for item in NSApplication.shared.orderedWindows {
            if (item.isVisible) { return true }
        }
        return false
        
    }
    
}



// main part:

let nsApplication: NSApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSApplication` has a [`windows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428402-windows) array. The value you want is just whether this array contains anything with [`isVisible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419132-isvisible) being true.

You would also need to check for [`isMiniaturized`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419699-isminiaturized) if you want to match the behaviour of the `flag` parameter, because apparently having a miniaturised window also causes a `true` to be passed to the flag.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428638-applicationshouldhandlereopen) of `applicationShouldHandleReopen`.

> Miniaturized windows, windows in the Dock, are considered visible by this method, and cause flag to return true, despite the fact that miniaturized windows return false when sent an `isVisible` message.

So the expression would be:

```
NSApplication.shared.windows.contains { $0.isVisible || $0.isMiniaturized }
```

Comment: I was using the updated code before your answer, I see there may be an issue in my code or your code, according to my experience until now a window that is closed or minimized by user is going count as invisible, so if we look to your code and we activated your code via `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` and give a good 5 sec to DispatchQueue before this time finish we are going minimize the app, then we wait your code would be returning true, but in the fact there is no window visible, yes it is minimized but it is still not visible.

Comment: If we run the same `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` with my code and before finishing the 5 sec we minimize the app, after 5 sec we would get false value for hasVisibleWindows which is meaning correct answer, with your code we would get true which means wrong answer. I got confused a little.

Comment: @HelloCodes I cannot reproduce the behaviour in your second comment. Minimising the app, and then wait for the `asyncAfter` block to run produces true for the expression in my answer. And then if I click on the icon to cause `applicationShouldHandleReopen` to run, the `flag` is also true.

Comment: I put the all test app code for test.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding might be that you don't count miniaturised windows as "visible"? The `flag` parameter of `applicationShouldHandleReopen` *does* count it as "visible" though. So which behaviour do you want? If you don't count miniaturised windows as "visible", then just keep using the code in your update.

Comment: Then the issue was about the flag! I think like this, if window is closed or miniaturised it is not visible to eyes.